# Truth of a statement with implication

Tags: logic

Let $M$ be the set of pairs $\{(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),(4,8), \dots\}$ and $n,m > 0$. Is the following statement true or false:

If $(n,n)$ is an element of $M$, then $(n,2n)$ is also an element of $M$.

I think $(n,n)$ is not an element of $M$ because there are no elements like $(2,2)$ or $(5,5)$. So $(n,2n)$ is an element of $M$. 
Lets say "$(n,n)$ is an element of $M$" is statement $p$ and "$(n,2n)$ is an element of $M$" is statement $q$. Then the conclusion $p \rightarrow q$ should be true because $p \rightarrow q$ is true when NOT $p$ OR $q$ is true. But the statement doesn't make sense to be true. So is it true or not?

Comment: $p$ is false thus $(p\implies q)$ is true, for all $q$.

Comment: When you start by a false statement, you can say what you want after.

Comment: But from (n,n) out of M you cant conclude (n,2n) element of M or can you??

Comment: To conclude something,  you need start by a true statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we usually evaluate conditionals like 'if .. then ...' is by looking at the truth-values of the 'if' part and the 'then' part, and we say that the 'if .. then ..' statement is false only when the 'if' part is true, and the 'then' part is false. Otherwise, the 'if .. then ..' is considered to be true.

This takes some getting used to. For example, take 'if I live in Paris, then I live in Germany'. Everyone (well, everyone who knows that Paris is in France, not Germany) wants to say that this statement is false, but if I don't live in Paris, then the statement is considered true by the above logical analysis.

You might argue that the logical analysis is incorrect then, and some people do indeed say this, but as with all of math: we simply define things a certain way, and we figure out how useful it is. As it so happens, the above logical analysis is very useful in many situations, even if sometimes you get some strange situations. The trick is to learn when the mathematical/logical analysis is appropriate, and when it is not.

But as far as answering questions on logic exams go, and making your teachers happy, you should just bite the bullet and use the above analysis. So, in your original question, since "(n,n) is in M" is false, the whole 'if ... then' is true.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  And when you get better with logic, you'll come to appreciate why things are defined the way they are!

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the statement is logically true since $(n,n)$ is not an element of $M$. It is irrelevant what comes after "If $(n,n)$ is an element of $M$, then . . ."

You could even make some statement like "If $(n,n)$ is in $M$ then I will never die." This is a true statement as well.

Comment: Okay but from (n,n) in M you cant conclude (n,2n) in M. So that seems to be true

Comment: @Arjihad I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. No, you can't conclude that $(n,2n)$ is in $M$ from the fact that $(n,n)$ is not in $M$, but that fact is not relevant to the truth value of the statement as a whole.